# Jquery function on wordpress page - not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to add next jquery script: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/GezZy/)

But, i get only static list of li , instead fade in list as its on the jsfiddle example.

I am using "underscores.me" framework, i tried to add the script to the "customizer.js" file, i also tried to add the script to the page, one time i tried above the ul tag, and other time i tried under the ul tag - but nothing, still i get static list of li.

On source code of my site i see:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://*****/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://****/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
```

So jquery load good (i edited here the **** signs instead the site url)

My code (all this code is on same page):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function showTheList() {
var i = 1;
function showOne() {
if (i === 1) $('.ul li').hide();
$('ul li').eq(i - 1).delay(1000).fadeIn(1000, function() {
$('ul li').eq(i - 1).fadeOut(100, function() {
if (++i > 4) i = 1;
showOne();
});
});
}
showOne();
} );

</script>
<ul class='ul'>
<li>Hello</li>
<li>Out</li>
<li>There</li>
<li>World!</li>
</ul>          
<script>                      
$(document).ready(showTheList());
</script>
```

So... why the list not fade in-out like the example?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `showTheList` function in `$(document).ready()` handler? If you run it before your elements are ready, it will do nothing.

Comment: Hey thanks, i edited my question. i am not working with jquery a lot, so maybe i did something funny and wrong... check if you can :) thanks

Comment: You are calling the ready handlers wrong. You need to use `jQuery(document).ready( function() { //your code } );`. For example: `$(document).ready( function() { showTheList(); } );`. Also, you can remove the upper script ( function definition ) from ready handler and leave it as it was. See more at http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
        <ul class='aa'>
          <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

          <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>

          <?php query_posts( 'cat=3&orderby=date&order=ASC' ); ?> <!-- post from '3' category -->

          <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


            <li><a href="<?php the_field('news-link') ?>" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">   <?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

                 <?php endwhile; ?>

                 <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>


<script type="text/javascript">
function InOut( elem )
{
 elem.delay()
     .fadeIn(1)
     .delay(100)
.fadeOut(
          function(){
             if(elem.next().length > 0) // if there is a next element
               {InOut( elem.next() );} // use it
             else
               {InOut( elem.siblings(':first'));} // if not, then use go back to the first sibling

           }
         );
}





jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
jQuery('.aa li').hide();
InOut( jQuery('.aa li:first') );
});





</script>
```

The best way to use jquery on wordpress page is to add JQuery before it, and use (document).ready , instead $ mark. on this example here, in the answer, i am using other script then the script i added to my question, but its the same idea.